# CSS background image vanishes on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, background-image, background-size

so our site is built on a CMS and is using CMS driven background images on our banners, as such the banners has inline styles on the html element dictating what the background-image was. This all worked fine.

I made a change so that the css is in a style tag just before the element so there is no 'inline styles' on the pages.

This works fine on desktop, when resizing and using mobile browser simulators, but on 2 Android phones I've tested on some pages the banner image shows for a split second and then vanishes. The confusing thing is all the banners on the site use the same css and html, but only certain ones break.

The ones I know that break are on the 'Web Development' and 'Contact Us' pages.

This is not something I have seen happen before, and there is no difference between code on each page, no javascript touching these, and they worked before I made recent changes (of which the only bit effecting these was moving the style from inline into a style tag).

Working page:
https://www.pixelhero.co.uk/web-design-bristol/

Not working:
https://www.pixelhero.co.uk/about-us/

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Or able to check if they see the same problem?

Image file sizes and dimensions don't seem to have any impact either (as often used to be the case)

I'm lost on this one, and can't seem to find an explanation for this use case.

Thanks all

Comment: Dude changing style= to <style>blah</style> is still "inline styles". Anyway, what if you change your file path on there to ../files/6014/blahblahblah

Comment: Will give it a go but the path is the same on the working pages too, and putting it in style tags is not 'inline styles' its 'in-page styles' and have different benefits. For example Google recommends no in-line styles, but does suggest in-page styles to display above the fold content (albeit in the head element).